# Copy string array to another array object

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, arraylist

I have an array of strings:

```
var a = new string[] { "a", "b", "b" };
```

and a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyField[] MyField {get; set;}
}
```

where `MyField` is a class:

```
public class MyField
{
    public InnerField[] InnerField{get; set;}
}
```

where `InnerField` is:

```
public class InnerField 
{
    public string Output {get; set;}
}
```

So I would like to copy from my array `(a)` to `MyField[]`.

Is it possible to make it by e.g LINQ?

Comment: In between MyField and Output, there is InnerField array. Thus you are trying to map from array to array of arrays, aren't you? How do you want to map it? What is the "rule"?

Comment: I got this from service.

Comment: @Cieja did you even try any of the given answers?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
var a = new string[] { "a", "b", "b" };
var innerFields = a.Select(s => new InnerField { Output = s });
var mc = new MyClass
{
    MyField = a.Select(s => new MyField { InnerField = innerFields.ToArray() }).ToArray()
};
```

If you even want to use the same `InnerField[]` reference don't use `innerFields.ToArray()` at the assignement but already at declaration of `innerFields`. Then all `MyField` instances refer to the same array.

If you only want one instance of `MyField` in the `MyField` array:

```
var mc = new MyClass
{
    MyField = new[]{ new MyField { InnerField = innerFields.ToArray() }}
};
```